# Add elements to ElementSelect via Javascript

Tags: plugin-development

I'm developing a plugin that works with Spotify's API. I'm wondering if can I add elements to a ElementSelect field. I do have the IDs of the elements I want to add.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you need something like this (using jQuery):

```
$('#yourID').append( '<option value="value">text</option>' );
```